# Building-Problems with TimeSynchronizer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - I want to subscribe two topics of the Kinect (synchron).
I followed the TimeSynchronizer Tutorial, but I have following errors when I build the code:

```
error: CMakeFiles/example.dir/src/test.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()'
error: note: 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1
```

error: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the important part:

```
void callback (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& input_image, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& input_depth) { 
//opencv stuff
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "hole_detection");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    cv::namedWindow("matches");
    cv::namedWindow("depth");

    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image_sub(nh, "camera/rgb/image_rect_color", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub(nh, "camera/depth_registered/image_rect", 1);

    TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> sync(image_sub, depth_sub, 10);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

    ros::spin ();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60801/building-problems-with-timesynchronizer/) by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am assuming you are using rosmake and not catkin to build your node. In your CMakeLists.txt file add the following lines:

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories ()
rosbuild_link_boost (${BINNAME} signals)
```

where `${BINNAME}` is the name of the executable you are building with `rosbuild_add_executable`. Note that you have to add those two lines *after* the line with `rosbuild_add_executable`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1